# mysql 5.7 - ubuntu 21.04

Tags: mysql, 21.04

Is it possible to install mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 21.04?
I have tried this : https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-focal/
But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That is for 20.04 not 21.04 a different series of products. 20.04 is an LTS version.

Comment: Short answer is "yes, but ...". If you really want to do this, the best way is to wrap it in a VM or a Docker container. If this is something you'd be interested in doing, I can write up a proper answer.